# In LINQ what is the proper method to delete all records in a secondary table?

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

VS2013, VB, EF, LINQ

These are relevant parts of my class definition:

```
Partial Public Class ApplicationDbContext
  Public Property ChannelItems As DbSet(Of ChannelItem)
  Public Property UserPosts As DbSet(Of UserPost)
End Class

Public Class ChannelItem
  Public Property ChannelItemID As Integer
  Public Property Anchor As New UserPost
  Public Property Comments As New List(Of UserPost)
  Public Property SpecialPermissionReq As Boolean
End Class

Public Class UserPost
  Public Property UserPostID As Integer
  ...
  Public Property MarkedAsAnswerBy As New List(Of MarkedAsAnswerBy)
End Class

Public Class MarkedAsAnswerBy
  Public Property MarkedAsAnswerByID As Integer
  Public Property UserName As String
End Class
```

During development I of course populated records into MarkedAsAnswerBy.  Note that at present, MarkedAsAnswerBy is not declared as a separate DbSet().  Navigation via the ChannelItem/UserPost meets the current need.

But during an "update-database" in the course of a migration the seed method threw an error because I was deleting the UserPost DbSet() records before rebuilding it.  SQL was offended because the secondary table had active links to UserPost records; makes perfect sense.  So I added the following to clear out that Key connection:

```
Dim listofUserPost = context1.UserPosts.Include(Function(x) x.MarkedAsAnswerBy).ToList()
For Each item In listofUserPost
  item.MarkedAsAnswerBy.RemoveAll(Function(x) x.MarkedAnsweredByID >= 0)
Next
```

The seed method then ran fine, which was great.  But I noticed that my code only changed the Key field in MarkedAsAnswerBy to Null.  I now see why, that's what RemoveAll with a predicate does.

I can't actually remove records in MarkedAsAnswerBy in a For Each loop because of the restriction against modifying the collection by deleting records while in an enumeration.  But I would like to remove the records instead of leaving them in the table.

What is a way I can do this without declaring the DbSet() for MarkedAsAnswerBy?

Comment: If you use a `For i = last to 0 Step - 1` then you can iterate the collection while removing since the index is going down and won't be larger than the collection.

Comment: So that makes sense regarding handling the enumeration.  However, when I attempted it with **thisChannelItem.Anchor.MarkedAsAnswerBy.RemoveAt(0)** I see it is still merely setting the Key field to Null in MarkedAsAnswerBy, not deleting the record.  So, you definitely answered how to handle the enumeration part - thx.  Any suggestions for actually deleting the record in the secondary table?  Or am I going to have to declare the DbSet() to be able to actually delete the record?

Comment: You will need to use the DbSet and query and remove those that match by Id.

Comment: Got it.  That confirms what I was trying to find out and ultimately answers the question, with extra knowledge gained as well.  I also noticed that creating a property as a DbSet() doesn't actually create the need for a migration; it is simply a definition in the project, which I previously didn't understand.  BTW, your responses are the answer, but I can't mark the question as answered.  If you write it up as an answer I will mark it, or if not, I'll write the answer later if I see you do not.  Thx again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `For i = last to 0 Step - 1` then you can iterate the collection while removing since the index is going down and won't be larger than the collection.

For the secondary tables you will need to use the `DbSet` and query and remove those that match by Id.